# "About" page not working when using a fresh hugo apero build

Tags: r, blogdown

I followed the exact same instruction as described here:
https://hugo-apero-docs.netlify.app/start/setup/

Everthing works, I can stage, commit and push from within R Studio to GitHub. Now I want to get the Apero site up and running using:

```
library(blogdown)

new_site(theme = "hugo-apero/hugo-apero", 
         format = "toml",
         sample = FALSE,
         empty_dirs = TRUE)
```

When asked whether the site should be served I chose `y`

> Want to serve and preview the site now? (y/n)

The site builds with no errors in R Studio, however, when I click the `About` section, I get this error below (all other sections work, i.e. `Blog`, `Projects`, etc.)...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spenting days searching for this solution, i've found it. I made a pull request in the theme documentation, you can look for it in the link below.

https://github.com/hugo-apero/hugo-apero-docs/pull/121

But explaining it here, you must change the a value in the `_index.md` file, located in `content/about` path. There, change  the `Headless = true`, to `false`, and the 'About' section gonna show up.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and give a brief description how to fix the error. I know you provided a link but a quick explanation in your answer would be wonderful! Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).